# Helping with this jquery script that is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that I want to run. I want a message to pop up in red if there is a textbox that isn't filled when the submit button is pressed. I want this message to pop up to the corresponding textbox. However, no matter what I do with the jQuery Script simply won't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstname').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_name = input.val();
    if (is_name) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  $('#lastname').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_name = input.val();
    if (is_name) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });


  $('#email').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    var is_email = re.test(input.val());
    if (is_email) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });


  $('#phone').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var re = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
    var is_phone = re.test(input.val());
    if (is_phone) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  $('#postcode').keyup(function(event) {
    var input = $(this);
    var re = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
    var is_postcode = re.test(input.val());
    if (is_email) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  $("submit button").click(function(event) {
    var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();
    var error_free = true;
    for (var input in form_data) {
      var element = $("#contact_" + form_data[input]['name']);
      var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
      var error_element = $("span", element.parent());
      if (!valid) {
        error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
        error_free = false;
      } else {
        error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
      }
    }
    if (!error_free) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      alert('No errors: Form will be submitted');
    }
  });



});
```

```css
.error {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.error_show {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" action="/submit.php" method="post">
  First name *:
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><span class="error">This field is required</span>
  <br/>Last name *:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><span class="error">This field is required</span>
  <br/>Email *:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="email"><span class="error">This field is required</span>
  <br/>Phone Number *:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="phone"><span class="error">This field is required</span>
  <br/>Post Code *:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="postcode"><span class="error">This field is required</span>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="accept" id="accept">Please add me to your mailing list *<span class="error">This field is required</span>
  <br/>
  <span>* required fields</span>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Will be nice see some online demo

Comment: You can use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to create a online demo to play with.

Comment: There are a lot of simple errors in here to get past first. Eg, `$("submit button")` is not an ID and the `postcode` check was pasted and still references `is_email`.

Comment: `$("submit button")` won't work a) because there is no submit element, and b) even if there was, you code has no button element that is a child of one.

Comment: @Nick: hey did my suggestion work for you? if it did, can you select it as the right answer please. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems:

- Your `input` elements in your HTML need to have the `name` attribute set correctly. Currently, pretty much all of them have a value of `lastname`.
- Your `click` handler for `submit` button is not correctly laid out. It needs to point to: `$("input[type=submit]")`.
- And lastly, your `element` variable doesn't really refer correctly to any of the `input` fields because the way you are forming the value for this variable is wrong. It should be like this: `var element = $("input[name=" + form_data[input]['name'] + "]");`.

Take a look at the snippet below.

***Snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstname').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var is_name = input.val();
        if (is_name) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });
    $('#lastname').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var is_name = input.val();
        if (is_name) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });
    $('#email').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
        var is_email = re.test(input.val());
        if (is_email) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });
    $('#phone').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var re = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
        var is_phone = re.test(input.val());
        if (is_phone) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });
    $('#postcode').keyup(function (event) {
        var input = $(this);
        var re = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
        var is_postcode = re.test(input.val());
        if (is_email) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function (event) {
        var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();
        var error_free = true;
        for (var input in form_data) {
            var element = $("input[name=" + form_data[input]['name'] + "]");
            var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
            var error_element = $("span", element.parent());
            if (!valid) {
                error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
                error_free = false;
            } else {
                error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
            }
        }
        if (!error_free) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert('No errors: Form will be submitted');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.error_show {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" action="/submit.php" method="post">First name *:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /><span class="error">This field is required</span>
    <br/>Last name *:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /><span class="error">This field is required</span>
    <br/>Email *:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><span class="error">This field is required</span>
    <br/>Phone Number *:
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><span class="error">This field is required</span>
    <br/>Post Code *:
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" /><span class="error">This field is required</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="accept" id="accept" />Please add me to your mailing list *<span class="error">This field is required</span>
    <br/> <span>* required fields</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been beat by Tahir but given I was half way through writing this here you go.

Here's a working copy of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/e0wjn5dp/.

Lots of small tweaks which needed making. I'll list them here and if you need anything expanding leave a comment:

1. Rather than hooking into the click event of the submit button, hook into the submit event of the form:

   `$("submit button").click(function(event) {}`

   becomes

   `$("#contact").submit(function(event) {}`
2. When looping through the form fields you're trying to find an ID of #contact_firstname, then #contact_lastname for example, these don't exist. Instead, look for children of the form containing the corresponding name instead:

   `var element=$(this).find("#" + form_data[input]['name']);`
3. In your postcode keyup event you're checking `if (is_email)` which doesn't exist, it should instead be `if (is_postcode)`
4. When finding your error element using `var error_element = $("span", element.parent());` you return all of the error spans. Instead, you can just use next to find the correct one assiciated with this field:

   `var error_element=element.next("span")`
5. Due to how your validation works it was necessary to add a `valid` class to the accept checkbox, otherwise validation would always fail. I also removed the error span associated to the checkbox, given the nature of it is that any state is valid.

But in all honesty, unless you really want to understand how to write your own validation logic, or have a specific reason to be writing your own I'd just use [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) which would let you do exactly what you want with minimal effort.

Full code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstname').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var is_name = input.val();
        if (is_name) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });

    $('#lastname').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var is_name = input.val();
        if (is_name) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });


    $('#email').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
        var is_email = re.test(input.val());
        if (is_email) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });


    $('#phone').on('input', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var re = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
        var is_phone = re.test(input.val());
        if (is_phone) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });

    $('#postcode').keyup(function (event) {
        var input = $(this);
        var re = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
        var is_postcode = re.test(input.val());
        if (is_postcode) {
            input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        } else {
            input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
        }
    });

    $("#contact").submit(function (event) {
        var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();
        var error_free = true;
        for (var input in form_data) {
            var element = $(this).find("#" + form_data[input]['name']);
            var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
            var error_element = element.next("span")
            if (!valid) {
                error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
                error_free = false;
            } else {
                error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
            }
        }
        if (!error_free) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert('No errors: Form will be submitted');
        }
    });



});
```